# string indices must be integers while passing ObjectId through URL in Django

Tags: python, django, mongodb, djongo

I am building a website in django and using mongodb as a database. I want to pass the objectID of mongodb document through url. I am applying the custom filter on it, but I am keep getting this error "string indices must be integers" on 'object|mongo_id' what am I doing wrong?
Here is my code:

user.html

```
{% load get_id %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div  style="padding-left: 1200px;" class="container-fluid">
      
        
          <button  class="btn btn-danger navbar-btn"><a href="{% url 'login_view' %}">Log Out</a></button>
        </div>
      </nav>
      
      <br>

      <div style="padding-left: 1100px;">
      <button  type="button" class="btn btn-success"> <a href="{% url 'new_job' object|mongo_id %}">Post Job</a> </button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

get_id.py

```
from django import template

register=template.Library()


@register.filter(name="mongo_id")
def mongo_id(value):
    return str(value['_id'])
```

Comment: Can you tell us what line triggers the error? Also, can you print `value['_id']` and tell us what is it? Same for `value` please.

Comment: button  type="button" class="btn btn-success"> <a href="{% url 'new_job' object|mongo_id %}">Post Job</a> </button> this line trigger the error

Comment: And its not printing any thing  giving the same error.

Comment: You have to check what `value` is. Where is it coming from? What is the expected value of `value['_id']`? Also, as a general remark, try giving meaningful names to your variables, calling a dictionary `value` is the best way to make your code difficult to read and maintain.